# Values in a Dictionary are getting replaced by last value in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary type variable where I'm keeping "string" type key and "List " type values.

The problem is, in case of loop all the previous values are getting replaced by the last value.

Why this happens?

```
        List<IWebElement> indicationsElement = ReturnIndicationList();
        drugsDB = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < indicationsElement.Count;i++ )
        {
            string key = indicationsElement[i].Text.ToString();
            dt = ZittarPatt.getDrugsByIndication(ClientName, key);
            drugsDB.Clear();

            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++)
            {
                drugsDB.Add(dt.Rows[k].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim());
            }
            drugsByindicationDictionary.Add(key, drugsDB);
        }
```

Comment: `List<T>` is a reference type. [Read this](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) and you'll be able to find what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the same reference every iteration instead of adding new instance of `List<string>`.
Every time you use `.Clear` it clears all the entries at `drugsByindicationDictionary` which are already the same entry.
Thus, only the last addition to `drugsDB` will be saved. (No `.Clear` is used at the end)

You should do the following code:

```
List<IWebElement> indicationsElement = ReturnIndicationList();
for (int i = 0; i < indicationsElement.Count;i++ )
{
    string key = indicationsElement[i].Text.ToString();
    dt = ZittarPatt.getDrugsByIndication(ClientName, key);
    var drugsDB = new List<string>();

    for (int k = 0; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++)
    {
        drugsDB.Add(dt.Rows[k].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim());
    }
    drugsByindicationDictionary.Add(key, drugsDB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `drugsDB.Clear();` to  `drugsDB = new List<string>();`